# AWS Glue Python Shell Import H3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, h3

Am trying to import h3 into a Python Glue Shell job, have downloaded the .whl file from https://pypi.org/project/h3/#files but am getting the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h3._cy.cells'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized need to use the specific whl file for py3.6 and x86_64
h3-3.7.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl

Comment: Awesome! If that's working for you, I think you can mark the question as answered (or self-answered), which might be useful for folks who run into the same issue in the future.